# How To Use range?

Tags: python, string, range

When I try to define a dictionary, what I want is:
`Today['Today_1' : 5.0, 'Today_2': 5.0, 'Today_3' : 5.0, ... 'Today_24' : 5.0]`. 
So I write:

```
Today = {}
for i in range(1,25,1):
    Today['Today_%s'%(i)]= 5.0 
print Today
```

Then I am so surprised when I saw the output. It is :

```
('Today_20': 5.0, 'Today_21' : 5.0,......'Today_16' : 5.0)
```

It did not start from 1. It was random.

It is a big problem for me.Because I Always do something like this, I have 50 files, they are `atom_1.dat, atom_2.dat, atom_3.dat, ..., atom_50.dat`. I use

```
for i in range(1,51,1):
   readfile('atom_%s.dat',%(i))
```

If it didn't start from 1, then I would have big trouble.

What is the problem??

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. Your code is working exactly as expected.

Comment: If you want an ordered dict, use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: There is no problem. You are using Python dictionaries which are unordered by nature.

Comment: The loop will work in order. It is the dictionary which did the unordered thing.

Comment: But the 'readfile' thing is ordered, right?

Comment: But that's not a big deal because you'll access your dictionary by using ordered keys if you loop with `range()` which will produce values in the same order you create them.

Comment: You could find that out on your own: 1. `print` somethin in your `range()` loop, 2. read the docs of `range()` and of `dict`. 3. draw your conclusions form your observations. 4. If then there are some questions left, ask here.

Comment: _If it didn't start from 1, then I would have big trouble._ - It DOES start from 1, however i strongly suggest that you read some of the answers below since they provide useful information.

Answer (score 4):

Using OrderedDict would solve all your worries...

```
import collections
Today = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in range(1,25,1):
    Today['Today_%s'%(i)]= 5.0 
print Today
```

Comment: range default step is 1, you can also use `today = collections.OrderedDict(('Today_%s'%(i),5.0) for i in xrange(1,25))`

Comment: Yes.. that would be a single line solution for it.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries in python are inherently unordered objects. If you want a dictionary which remembers the order that objects are inserted have a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

To use this you will want to replace the line

```
Today = {}
```

with

```
import collections
Today = collections.OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call print Today, it actually called the dict.**str**() method, this output is disorder doesn't mean your insert is not in ordered, you can work round like this:

```
class Today(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        retval = []
        for eachKey in sorted(self.keys()):
            retval.append("'" + eachKey + "'" + ":" + str(self[eachKey]))
        return ",".join(retval)


today = Today()
for i in range(1, 25, 1):
    today['Today_%s' % i] = 5.0
print today
```